# Scala 3 macro: generic type from class

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, scala-reflect

I am writing a serialization library using Scala 3 macro programming.
I want to generate the serializer dynamicly. Because this is a library, so I do not know what class to serializer during compile. So I need a runtime compile feature.

Code:

```
object CodecMacro {
    import scala.quoted.staging.*
    given Compiler = Compiler.make(getClass.getClassLoader)
    
    // function 1: entry point: a Class object
    def buildSerializer(clazz: Class[_]): Serializer = {
        given staging.Compiler = staging.Compiler.make(getClass.getClassLoader)
        val fn = (qctx: Quotes) ?=> {
            given q: Quotes = qctx
            buildSerializerAdapter(clazz)
        }
        staging.run(fn)
    }
    
    // function 2: convert clazz to generic T
    // My main question is here
    private def buildSerializerAdapter(clazz: Class[_])(using quotes: Quotes): Expr[Serializer] = {
        import quotes.reflect.*
        val tpe: TypeRepr = TypeRepr.typeConstructorOf(clazz)
        val t = tpe.asType
        type T = t.Underlying
        buildSerializerImpl[T]  // error： Missing type parameters for T
    }
    
    // function 3: Using a generic T to generate a Serializer
    private def buildSerializerImpl[T: Type](using quotes: Quotes): Expr[Serializer] = {
        val t = summon[Type[T]]
        '{
            type T = t.Underlying
            new Serializer[T] {
            override def serialize(writer: Writer, value: T): Unit = {
            // Implemetation, not important
            writer.writeString("aaa")
        }
    }
}
```

Function 1 is the entry point, which needs a Class object.
Function 3 is the final implementation, which needs a generic type T.

Function 2 is to convert from Class object to generic type T and this is my main question.

My solution is

```
    Class ->  TypeRepr  use: TypeRepr.typeConstructorOf(clazz)
    TypeRepr -> Type    use: TypeRepr.asType
    Type -> type T      use: Type.Underlying
```

I thought the type T under Type will solve my problem, but the compiler gives me an error:
"Missing type parameters for T"

In Function 3:
`type T = t.Underlying`
`value: T`
The generic type T is working fine.

Is there any way to convert Class object to generic type T?

Comment: Where is defined the function `buildCodecCode`??

Comment: Sorry, it should be "buildSerializerAdapter". Corrected

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way it should be done:

```scala
        tpe.asType  match
            case '[t] =>
                buildSerializerImpl[t]
```

This very strange invocation comes straight from [the documentation of asType](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.0/scala/quoted/Quotes$reflectModule$TypeReprMethods.html#asType-245). It is necessary because `asType` returns a `Type[?]` where `Type` accepts any type kind, but here we want a concrete type kind. The match would fail if the type was of higher kind, such as a `Type[List]` (the `List` constructor takes type arguments).